# Why loading attribute is not working in chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, lazy-loading

I have replaced lazy loading with native chrome `loading="lazy"` attribute but it seems to be not working. I am using Chrome 76 latest version.

I checked my page speed in https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights and it still shows to Defer offscreen images!

Not sure what exactly I have missed?

```
<img class="img-fluid" loading="lazy" src="my-image-path" />
<img class="img-fluid" loading="lazy" src="my-image-path" />
<img class="img-fluid" loading="lazy" src="my-image-path" />
<img class="img-fluid" loading="lazy" src="my-image-path" />
<img class="img-fluid" loading="lazy" src="my-image-path" />
```

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, can you check if running `'loading' in HTMLImageElement.prototype` in your console returns `true`?

Comment: `loading' in HTMLImageElement.prototype` returns true for me @CodyMacPixelface but the `loading="lazy"` has no effect. Lighthouse reports that it has not been added as well

Comment: Same here. Opera 67.0.3575.97 (WebKit).

Comment: See possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61867237/5802289

Answer (score 3):

I answered a related question some time ago:

After some research I found that I was missing something on my images. **Images should include dimension attributes**

As mentioned here: https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/#images-should-include-dimension-attributes

While it's not necessary, it is desired or expected to specify the dimension attributes on your images because without dimensions specified, layout shifts can occur. Resulting in unexpected behavior.

The browser needs to know the dimensions of your images to reserve sufficient space on a page for them.

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64330480/10757314

Comment: You can accomplish the same thing using the `aspect-ratio` CSS property as well.